# Como redimensionar imagenes con PHP

Tags: php

Estimados necesito saber lo siguiente, como se puede rellenar la altura faltante de una imagen con unas franjas de color negro o blanco. Estoy intentando lo siguiente, si alguien en mi web sube una imagen con un ancho mayor a 1200px, redimensiono el ancho a 1200px y el alto lo calculo por regla de tres. Pero si el nuevo alto es menor a 675px me gustaria rellenar lo faltante con unas franjas color blanco o color negro dependiendo del caso. Ya tengo unas lineas de codigo implementadas donde a traves de un input file las imagenes se envian y son procesadas con PHP. Aun no hago las validaciones de las medidas, pero estoy mientras probando el redimensionar. Solo me faltaria saber como relizar dicho procedimiento.

Adjunto el codigo

```
$ruta = '../imagenes/'; 
session_start();
$idusuario = $_SESSION['idusuario'];
$cod = explode('USER',$idusuario);
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$idmascota = $cod[1].$this->idmascota($nombre);
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES);$i++){   
   $anchomax = 1200;
   $altomax = 675;
   $nombreoriginal = $_FILES['imagen'.$i]['name'];
   $nombretemporal = $_FILES['imagen'.$i]['tmp_name'];
   $ext = pathinfo($nombreoriginal, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $nombrefinal = $idmascota.'_'.$i.'.'.$ext;
   $destino = $ruta.$nombrefinal;
   $dimensiones = getimagesize($nombretemporal);
   $ancho = $dimensiones[0];
   $alto = $dimensiones[1];
   $imagen_p = imagecreatetruecolor(1200, 675);
   $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($nombretemporal);
   imagecopyresampled($imagen_p, $imagen, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1200, 675, $ancho, $alto);
   /* Sobreescribimos la imagen original con la reescalada */
   imagejpeg($imagen_p, $nombretemporal);
   move_uploaded_file($nombretemporal,$destino);
}
```

Comment: he utilizado exitosamente la librería https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.imagick.php, la extensión esta soportada oficialmente por PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Existen ocasiones en las que las extensiones de PHP u otras librerías no soportan imágenes con ciertas características o, en otras ocasiones se trababan o regresaban error,  por lo que opté por usar ImageKit ([Aquí](https://imagekit.io/)).

Es un CDN extremadamente bueno, solamente hay que crear una cuenta gratis que, te da 20 GB de ancho de banda, bastantes buenos. Una vez creada la cuenta te dará un ID para usar en la URL, también hay que configurar el acceso del CDN a tu espacio donde almacenas los recursos originales.

Una vez hecho eso, solamente hay que usar las URL de la siguiente forma, para redimensionar las imágenes:

```
https://ik.imagekit.io/your_imagekit_id/default-image.jpg?tr=w-300,h-300
```

Redimensionar conservando la relación de aspecto, usando imagen progresiva

```
https://ik.imagekit.io/your_imagekit_id/default-image.jpg?tr=w-300,pr
```

O para reducir la calidad de la imagen, optimizándola para Web, poniendo la mitad de la calidad

```
https://ik.imagekit.io/your_imagekit_id/default-image.jpg?tr=q-50,
```

Consultando esas URL obtienes un respuesta que puedes manejar usando `file_get_contents()`, de la siguiente manera:

```
$url = str_replace(' ', '%20', $url); //Para reemplazar espacios (por posibles nombres de archivos con espacios) 
$img = file_get_contents($url); // $img ya sería el elemento que pondrías en tu código para guardar un recurso.
```

Son solo unos ejemplos y puedes crear muchísimas cosas con ese CDN de ImageKit, como collages, agregar los bordes que requieres a las otras imágenes, y demás posibilidades que puedes consultar [aquí](https://docs.imagekit.io/features/image-transformations/)